# Angular2 CanActivate global function declaration

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I like to implement `@CanActivate(() => checkpermission())` in all my component. Here i am facing one issue.

```
checkpermission is not a function
```

how to declare function globally. For global function, now i am using services. Is it possible to call service function inside

```
@CanActivate(() => checkpermission())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it global this way,

NOTE : This ans may contain some extra stuffs (which probably you don't require). So you may concentrate on the things you require and ignore other unrequired stuffs. I have put this ans by considering more global scenario(eg - what if you want to inject some external service into checkpermission function)

***checkpermission.ts***

```
import {Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {appInjector} from './app-injector';
import {externalService} from './externalService'; <---------------------- //some external service
import {Router, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';

export const checkpermission= (next: ComponentInstruction, previous: ComponentInstruction) => {

    let injector: Injector = appInjector(); // get the stored reference to the injector
    let externalService: externalService= injector.get(externalService);
    let router: Router = injector.get(Router);

    // return a boolean or a promise that resolves a boolean

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

                       //here you can play with externalService

                        if(something is true)
                           resolve(true);
                        else 
                           resolve(false);

    });
};
```

---

***somecomponent.ts***

In somecomponent  you can use **checkpermission.ts** like this,

```
import {checkpermission} from './checkpermission';

@CanActivate((next: ComponentInstruction, previous: ComponentInstruction) => {
       return checkpermission(next, previous);        
})
```

---

***app-injector.ts***

```
import {Injector} from 'angular2/core';

let appInjectorRef: Injector;
export const appInjector = (injector?: Injector):Injector => {
    if (injector) {
      appInjectorRef = injector;
    }

    return appInjectorRef;
};
```

I hope it will fulfill you requirement.

Comment: You are welcom @deepk . Please use it according to your needs. This ans may contain some extra things(just for the reference by considering the global scenario).

Comment: okay @micronyks. Is it possible to call this global function with parameter inside class?

Comment: What do you mean by it?

Comment: @Deepakrao. Yes it is possible to use it with parameter, within component class.

Comment: ok can please comment it. because i need to call function with paramter if i get 403 from server. it may be in any component inside event function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107511/discussion-between-deepak-rao-and-micronyks).